# How to get the right data from MySQl?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a login-page which allows users to log-in after registeration.
I have also a form that allows the loged-in users to sunbmit a advertisment.

I get the submitted data in my database.
My databse has 2 tabels.
First one (users) is for users to register and the second one (adver) is for the advertisement data.
In my 'adver' table I have a column which gets the first_name of the user, after submitting the form.

My question is how to display the user information next to the submitted advirtesment by that same user!?

Comment: You should show your table's schemas, and some initial code. Help us to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysql Join query.

First of all, assign a unique id to every user (which is an obvious thing), if the registered user submits the advertisement then use his registered unique id in the advertisement table.

See the explanation below:

[image]

To implement this, you can refer [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a userId present in both the table you can try with:

```
Select 
*
from 
users u
inner join advertisements a on (u.userId = a.userId)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
*
from 
users u
inner join advertisements a on (u.first_name = a.first_name)
```

Comment: Thx it works, but I think I need also to rewrite the url so each advertisement would has his own 'unique' url.. right?

Comment: yes i would recommend that, like Butterfruit showed you